# How to use Fluent API for creating a simple one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Let me first give some background: I'm creating an application, which should handle a DB. That DB might evolve (extra tables/columns/constraints might be added, but nothing gets removed, in fact the DB gets more and more elaborated).

I started with a "Database First" approach and as a result, I have created an Entity Framework diagram, with according classes in `*.cs` files. Two of those files are (only some interesting fields):

### Area.cs:

```
public partial class Area
{
    public Area() {  }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

### Location.cs:

```
public partial class Location
{
    public Location() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public Nullable<int> AreaId { get; set; }
}
```

This is generated from a version of the DB, which does not cover constraints, and now I would like to add a `ForeignKeyConstraint` to the corresponding Entity Framework model:

- `Location.AreaId` is a foreign key towards `Area.Id`
- There are many `Location` objects for one `Area` object
- It's the idea to prevent deletion of `Area` objects, being referred to by `Location` objects).

I believe this should be done as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Area>().HasKey(t => t.Id);     // Creation of primary key
    modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasKey(t => t.Id); // Creation of primary key

    modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasRequired(n => n.AreaId)
                                   .WithMany(...)
                                   .HasForeignKey(n => n.AreaId);
    ...
```

This, obviously, does not work. I'm missing following information:

1. My "Area.cs" file does not contain a reference to the `Location` object (as this version of the DB does not contain constraints, this has not been added by the "database first" wizard), should I add this or can I solve my issue without?
2. What do I need to fill in instead of the ellipsis `.WithMany(...)`?
3. Extra question: I'm aware of the `ForeignKey` directive. Should I replace `public Nullable<int> AreaId { get; set; }` in "Location.cs" by `[ForeignKey("AreaId")]`, followed by `public virtual Area Area { get; set; }`?

**Edit**
Important remark: as "Location.cs" and "Area.cs" are auto-generated, I like to minimise changes in those files.

**Next edit**
Meanwhile I've updated my "Location.cs" file as follows:

```
...
// public Nullable<int> AreaId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("AreaId")]
public Area Area { get; set;}
....
```

My `OnModelCreating()` has been changed into:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasRequired(n => n.Area)
                               .WithMany(...)
                               .HasForeignKey(n => n.Area);
```

That leaves only the ellipsis problem to be solved.

**Another edit**
Since it takes such a long time for an answer (even for a comment), I've decided to add following line of source code to my "Area.cs" file:

```
public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
```

I've then filled in the ellipsis as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().HasRequired(l => l.Area)
                               .WithMany(a => a.Locations)
                               .HasForeignKey(l => l.Area);
```

Now just one question: how can I mention that the link between the `Area` and the `Location` should be handled by `Location.AreaId` and `Area.Id` (I know that `Location.AreaId` is the foreign key, but how can I know that it refers to `Area.Id`)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you ~~strike~~ or remove some questions if they are not necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your last question. EF is recognizing that `Area.Id` is a primary key so connects `Location.AreaId` to `Area.Id`

Also, [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx) is a simple guide on how to do it.

Comment: As far I can see, your `Area` has an `Id` field. And it's set by using FluentAPI to be a primary key so it should be ok. Also. Your `Location` class has `AreaId` property so still, it looks fine to me. Did it help?

Comment: I'm just wondering: what if a next table does not have an `Id`-like column, what should I do then?

Comment: Looks like a weird DB concept. You cannot create a relation if cannot identify an entity in DB. Even a multifield key is at least some key. I would recommend adding Id column to that table or rethink the whole DB schema.